# just_audio load mp3 from application documents directory

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I've been using just_audio to stream audio from Firebase Storage without a hitch. I've also been using it to download audio, saving the file to cache (temporary storage) and been able to load/play it just fine. However, recently the requirements have changed and the downloaded audio file needs to be persisted for longer duration than what OS specifies (files in cache get deleted after 1 day sometimes).

With the help of `path_provider` I'm able to get the application documents directory with `Directory tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, save the file, and have the path returned. But not able to load the file in to `just_audio`.

Using `just_audio_background`, previously I was loading cached files with:

```
var audioSourceBackground = AudioSource.uri(
  Uri.parse(url),
  tag: MediaItem(
    id: "",
    album: "",
    title: "",
  ),
);

await player.setAudioSource(audioSourceBackground));
```

Repeatedly I get the error code: `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-1002, unsupported URL, null, null)`. I have tried `Uri.file(url)` and `Uri.parse(url)`

Is there a solution to load downloaded audio file that is stored in application documents directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69112394/11118209

Comment: Assuming the file is saved as you claim (and hence it's not a permissions issue), are you saying that the very same logic works if you get the cache directory instead of the application document directory? I doubt that would be the case as I don't think simply changing the directory (assuming it's not a permissions issue) would have any effect on the logic. Maybe this question is not about which directory works, but which filename extension works, or something like that.